# Advanced map and filter with Python

Tags: php, python

I need to translate small feature from PHP to Python.

There is a JSON data source that I need to match according to the URI. Here's an example of the data:

```
[
    {
        "group": "fruits",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "apple",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "orange",
                "id": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "vegetables",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "tomato",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "carrot",
                "id": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "candies",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "chocolate",
                "id": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "cookie",
                "id": 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

There's an URI in a variable, for example `orange/carrot`, which should return an array of matched objects:

```
[
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "carrot",
        "id": 4
    }
]
```

It only can match them according to the data source order, so for example `carrot/orange` or `tomato/cookie` are not accepted. First URI segment needs to be found in the first group etc. If the URI appears as invalid, the result should be null.

Here's the PHP version I made:

```
$uri = 'apple/carrot';
$segments = explode('/', $uri);

$groups = json_decode(file_get_contents('data/food.json'));

$matches = array_map(function (string $segment, int $index) use ($groups): ?object {
    return array_values(array_filter($groups[$index]->members, function (object $item) use ($segment): bool {
        return $item->name === $segment;
    }))[0] ?? null;
}, $segments, array_keys($segments));

$matches = in_array(null, $matches) ? null : $matches;
```

And here's what I tried to do with Python:

```
import os, json

uri = 'apple/carrot'
segments = uri.split('/')

dataFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data/food.json')
groupsJSON = open(dataFilePath).read()
groups = json.loads(groupsJSON)

# Here I tried to work it out with map() and filter() or list comprehension

items = items if None not in items else None
```

I don't know what is "the Python way" to do it. Can you guys help with this transformation?

Comment: Tell me something, does the source JSON start with `[` or does it start with `{`?

Comment: It starts with the `[`. These groups are ordered.

Comment: Alright. Working on a solution.

Comment: Can you run `import pandas as pd` and `df = pd.read_json("your json file path")` and maybe attach a snapshot of what you see? I just need to understand how the `members` column looks when you read it in using `pd.read_json`

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'pandas'`

Comment: I'll come up with my answer. Give me a moment.

Comment: @RoboRobok `py pip install pandas` in the cmd to add it to your python environment. If might help to have a clearer view of the data to filter.

Comment: No need! I got it without `pandas`

Comment: Isn’t Python’s JSON handling clear without any libraries?

Comment: @RoboRobok YES! I don't need `pandas`. Since you want it to be ordered. Do me a favor and run `from collections import OrderedDict` and let me know if this line throws any errors.

Comment: You don't need pandas. pandas is not good at handling json-like data. @Abhishek of course he has `OrderedDict`, that's part of the std library.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I'm still learning man!

Answer (score 1):

This is my interpretation of "the python way"

```
import json
from typing import Optional

# uses python 3.6 type hints, feel free to remove
def func(uri: str, groups_json: str) -> Optional[str]:

    segments = uri.split('/')

    groups = json.loads(groups_json)

    # this a dictionary comprehension with a double for loop  
    members = {member['name']: member
               for group in groups
               for member in group['members']}

    # nb. this will throw a KeyError if segment is not valid --
    # maybe put in try / except KeyError block?
    items = [members[segment] for segment in segments]

    # make sure items are in a valid order
    if not sorted(items, key=lambda item: item['id']) == items:
        return None

    return json.dumps(items)

print(func('apple/carrot', groupsJSON))  
# --> [{"name": "apple", "id": 1}, {"name": "carrot", "id": 4}]

print(func('carrot/apple', groupsJSON))
# --> None
```

Comment: K nevermind. I'm not even going to bother answering since you got the solution right..

Comment: @Abhishek don't be disheartened. I'm sure you can come up with a cleaner way than this. Plus it's good practise.

Comment: You would puke if you see my nested for loops going into a list, and then into the dictionary and then into its key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use generator:

```
def search_members(items, needles):
    local_needles = needles.split('/')
    needle = local_needles.pop(0)
    all_found = False
    for item in items:
        for member in item['members']:
            if member['name'] == needle:
              yield member
              if local_needles:
                 needle = local_needles.pop(0)
              else:
                 all_found = True
                 break
        if all_found:
            break
```

I wasn`t able to find a scenario with better Time Complicity then this way

```
needles = 'orange/carrot'
result = list(search_members(items, needles))
```

And if wrong data suppled, for example you could raise exception after comparing both lengths

```
if len(result) != len(needles):
   raise Exception('Wrong data supplied for url!)
```

Comment: Please remember that the order of the groups is crucial here. I don't think `needles` can be a Set then.

Comment: @Robo Robok, ok, sorry, Wasn`t enough attentive to the question description. Hope now it`s better

Comment: I very much recommend against mutating an argument. `needles` will be empty after passing through this function. You could always accept a string and split it yourself. Also `lst.pop(0)` is an `O(len(lst))` operation, whereas indexing is `O(1)`.

Comment: Your indentation is still messed up. I can't actually run this program. You use four spaces and then three for indentation. Please stick with 4 as recommended by PEP8.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, I hope now it's ok.  Also, I don`t think lst.pop(0)  has O(len(lst)), because lists in python are LinkedList structures, so removing or adding element from/to a list takes constant amount of time

Comment: @Basalex No python lists are dynamically sized arrays. `lst.pop(0)` copies the entire array. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: For large lists, `pop(0)` is 1000 times slower than `pop()`: --- `x = list(range(10**8));

%timeit x.pop();
128 ns ± 1.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each) `....

`x = list(range(10**8));

%timeit x.pop(0);
115 ms ± 507 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`